# Active vs. Attentive vs. Machine Vision

Tags: image-processing

I would like to know a short definition of the three fields

- Active Vision
- Attentive Vision
- Machine Vision

For me it is quite hard to find a specific definition in literature. Sometimes authors group two of them together or use any of them as a synonym.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about programming -- maybe https://dsp.stackexchange.com is a better fit?

Comment: Yes indeed, I think its a mix between several fields. I have published it at dsp. Thx.